# How to sum count variable in PHP

Tags: php

i want to sum for some data which come from function foreach in PHP, but i found error while run it, here my simple code :

```
        <?php
            $no=1;
            foreach($data_tersimpan->result_array() as $dp)
            {
            ?>
            <?php 
            $total = 0;
            $total += count($dp['id_plan']);
            echo $total;
        ?>
         <?php
                $no++;
            }
         ?>
```

from my code above, i print `$total`, then data shown like this :

```
1   1   1   1   1
```

I want to get summary `5` if i print `$total`
is there any suggestion to make summary in php scrypt(not in sql query)?

THanks

Comment: You want `total` to be 5, or you want a separate variable (summary) to be 5?

Comment: `$total` to be 5

Comment: You didnt close the `foreach`

Comment: Then put `$total = 0;` before the loop, your resetting it each time to 0

Comment: define this `$total = 0;` out side of foreach and `echo $total;` after closing foreach you get count of total

Comment: @karisma : You have 3 years of experience and  this type of mistake ?

Comment: welcome sister :) happy coding

Comment: @karisma : what type of value you have in `$dp['id_plan']` ? may be it very easy to get from `mysql` instead `php`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you are resetting your total for every iteration of the loop.

```
<?php
    $total = 0;
    $no=1;
    foreach($data_tersimpan->result_array() as $dp) {
        $total += count($dp['id_plan']);
        $no++;
    }
    echo $total;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

you have misplaced `{}`& opening tag for PHP within in your PHP code .which causes error.have you enabled ERROR_display in your PHP ini file?

```
  <?php
            $no=1;
            $total = 0;
            foreach($data_tersimpan->result_array() as $dp)
            {
            $total += count($dp['id_plan']);
             }
            echo $total;
        ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

your code have some problem first you add total and every time assign total 0 so total not update and no need more php tag and also counter value

```
<?php
$total = 0; // first assign total 0
foreach ($data_tersimpan->result_array() as $dp) {
    $total += count($dp['id_plan']); // every time update total  = total + your value;
}
echo $total; // this is final total
?>
```

when loop complete then final output is total value, if no data found then final total will be 0.

Comment: sorry for accept answer i vote to the first time answer :)

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
    $no=1;
    $total = 0;
    foreach($data_tersimpan->result_array() as $dp) {
        $total += count($dp['id_plan']);
        $no++;
    }
    echo $total;
?>
```